# ¿Cómo hacer que dos columnas en un form HTML queden en la misma fila, con Materializa css?

Tags: html, css, materialize

Estoy haciendo un formulario HTML con Materializa css, pero no sé cómo hacer para que quede en la misma línea el `checkbox` y el `<input tipe="text">` Agrego mi HTML:

```
HTML
<div class="row section z-depth-2 ">
  <div class="col s3">
    <input type="checkbox" id='producto1'>
    <label for="producto1">Producto 1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-field col s9">
    <input type="number"  id="item" class="validate active">
    <label for="item" class="active">Cantidad</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col s3">
    <input type="checkbox" id='producto2'>
    <label for="producto2">Producto 2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-field col s9">
    <input type="number"  id="item2" class="validate active">
    <label for="item2" class="active">Cantidad</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Y este es el resultado, donde se puede ver el checkbox más arriba en vez de quedar en la misma línea que el `<input tipe="text">`:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supongo que quieres algo así:

```html
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="row sevction z-depth-2 ">
  <div class="input-field col s3">
    <label for="producto1">
        <input type="checkbox" id='producto1'>
        <span>Producto 1</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-field  col s9">
    <input type="number" id="item" class="validate active">
    <label for="item" class="active">Cantidad</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-field col s3">
    <label for="producto2">
        <input type="checkbox" id='producto2'>
        <span>Producto 2</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-field col s9">
    <input type="number" id="item2" class="validate active">
    <label for="item2" class="active">Cantidad</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Lo he hecho mirando [esta documentación](https://materializecss.com/checkboxes.html) para los checkboxes, y [esta otra documentación](https://materializecss.com/text-inputs.html) para los input, del sitio oficial de materialize.